# How to restart web ui on freenas

Tags: truenas

I've come across a bug with freenas where the web ui (lighthttpd) can freeze up and render the service to hang. Is there an easy way to restart this service via a terminal?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Current versions of FreeNAS use `nginx` and the Django framework. They can be restarted as follows:

```
service nginx restart
service django restart
```

or

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/nginx  restart
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/django restart
```

Comment: works for `FreeBSD freenas.local 9.3-RELEASE-p8 FreeBSD 9.3-RELEASE-p8 #1 r275790+18ab2bc: Wed Jan 21 12:32:31 PST 2015     root@build3.ixsystems.com:/tank/home/jkh/build/93/FN/objs/os-base/amd64/fusion/jkh/93/FN/FreeBSD/src/sys/FREENAS.amd64  amd64`

Answer (score 11):

For TrueNAS 12:

```
service middlewared restart
service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 2):

To restart lighthttpd, use:

```
/etc/rc.d/lighttpd restart
```