# FreeNAS Web UI not responding

Tags: truenas, graphical-user-interface

Our FreeNAS is running; I can login via ssh.

But the Web UI is not responding.

From [How to restart web ui on freenas](https://serverfault.com/questions/258584/how-to-restart-web-ui-on-freenas) I tried 
`service nginx restart`
which gave:

```
Performing sanity check on nginx configuration:
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Stopping nginx.
Waiting for PIDS: 2180.
Performing sanity check on nginx configuration:
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Starting nginx.
```

then `service django restart` and got:

```
cat: /var/run/django.pid: No such file or directory
usage: kill [-s signal_name] pid ...
       kill -l [exit_status]
       kill -signal_name pid ...
       kill -signal_number pid ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/www/freenasUI/manage.py", line 59, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/www/freenasUI/freeadmin/models.py", line 29, in <module>
    from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.7.egg/south/modelsinspector.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/generic.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.options import InlineModelAdmin, flatten_fieldsets
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.options import ModelAdmin, HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.contrib import messages
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from api import *
EOFError: EOF read where object expected
Starting django
```

GUI is still not working. Should I try `reboot` ? Or is there another way?

Comment: check whether /usr/local/www/freenasUI/manage.py is being started. If not try to find the reason why.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: ssh into server as privileged user. Execute 'ps auxwww | grep freenas'. Do you see "/usr/local/bin/python -R /usr/local/www/freenasUI/manage.py runfcgi method=threaded ..."? If so, kill the process with 'kill -15 PID_OF_PYTHON_PROCESS_MENTIONED_ABOVE'. If the process will still exist, perform 'kill -9 PID_OF_PYTHON_PROCESS_MENTIONED_ABOVE'. Then start django by issuing 'service django start' as privileged user.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation:

1. Failed install as described https://bugs.freenas.org/issues/18273 (i.e. the GUI Update said 20% and then halted)
2. Can `ssh` in
3. Library errors for the following:

   - `service django start`
   - `wget`
   - `beadm activate` (Grub errors, flagged the older boot as R but never booted into it.)
   - `freenas-update`
4. No physical access, so no choosing with Grub at startup.

My libraries were messed up! The fix?

1. mount the previous boot image:

   `$ mkdir /var/tmp/9.10.1-U4`

   `$ beadm mount 9.10.1-U4 /var/tmp/9.10.1-U4/`
2. restore previous libraries: `$ copy /var/tmp/9.10.1-U4/usr/local/lib/lib* /usr/local/lib`

Now `beadm activate` works. Switch to previous version, reboot, and follow Ajedi32's instructions (delete the broken boot version, try the update again).